# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I always get this error whenever i compile the code:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

I know that the error is in the array chosen[], but i think I initializated it correctly. Can anyone tell where the problem is?

```
 public  boolean[] chosen=new boolean[n];

 public void clear() {
     for (int k= 0; k < n; k++)
     {
    chosen[k] = false;

     }
```

I saw other answers on the same question , but none of them was helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: Bug is not in the provided code. There is only one way to fix those errors. See linked question.

Comment: I know this is a duplicate question , but none of the other answers was helpful to me

Comment: Is not a duplicate question. Is related on the sequence of operations performed. So it specific for this question. If you post again the question I can answer to it.

Comment: @Rii933 Just take a look at the java docs then: "Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array."

Comment: @LPK I hope that Rii933 knows what is an arrayOfBoundException and how to solve it. But the problem is subtle. It depends on the sequence of calls and on the default value of not setted variables.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO Yeah, and with a bit of understanding of his self-written code he is now able to find out why this error happens.

Comment: @LPK yes could be possible. But the reasons to close this question is wrong. This is not an already answered question. Is a complet new one.

Comment: I know what the exception means , I just don't know where exactly is the illegal index . Because it says that the problem is in the clear () method, in the  chosen[k] = false; line

Comment: @Rii933 well, k is your illegal index then... It is the only one in this line

Comment: why is k illegal? I think there is no error in it.

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate. This is not a "debugging my code" site.

Comment: @Raedwald is not a clear duplicate. It was reopened for this reason. If you find a different question that is similar to this one you are free to cast your close vote again. But check before if the related question is really similar to this one.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems

Comment: And you really think that is a debugger related question?!?

Comment: All bugs in programs manifest due to a particular sequence of operations in a program.

Comment: So any question asked on stackoverflow can be closed and related to that question on debuggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is related to the sequence of operations performed:

- You create the array `choosen` with the default value of the variable `n` that is 0 (when the object containing it was instantiated). Now the array has length 0.
- After you set `n` to a value different from 0.
- After you call the method `clear()`. In the method clear you try to access to an element not present in the array `choosen` because the array was previously created with size 0 and any modification to n doesn't affect the array.

Comment: I understand. 
I will try to correct it 
Thank you alot